# robocopy adds hidden symbol when creating folders

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

What I do, is copying photo files from SD card to HDD using powershell ps1 file and Windows PowerShell ISE.
I get a taken date from image exif and add it to destination path.
The problem is that robocopy creates folders and adds strange prefix, which I do not want to have.
As a result I can see two subfolders with same name "2020", one folder created by hand and the other created by robocopy.
This prefix is only seen when I list folders with CMD.
The prefix not seen in output.log and in powershell.

[image]

```
$copy_from = "G:\DCIM\100MSDCF\"
$copy_to = "C:\Photos\"

function GetDateTaken {
  param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [Alias('FullName')]
    [String]
    $Path
  )
  begin {
    $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
  }
  process {
    $returnvalue = 1 | Select-Object -Property Name, DateTaken, Folder
    $returnvalue.Name = Split-Path $path -Leaf
    $returnvalue.Folder = Split-Path $path
    $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($returnvalue.Folder)
    $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($returnvalue.Name)
    $returnvalue.DateTaken = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 12)

    $returnvalue.DateTaken
  }
}

$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $copy_from -recurse -include ('*.jpg','*.arw')

$i = 0
$jpg = 0
$arw = 0

$logifile = 'output.log'

if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($logifile)) {
    Clear-Content $logifile
    Write-Host ("Logfile cleaned: $logifile")
} else {
    try {
        New-Item -Path . -Name $logifile | Out-Null
        Write-Host ("New logfile created: $logifile")
    }
    catch {
        "Failed to create $logifile"
    }
}

foreach ($file in $file) {

    if ($file.extension -eq '.JPG') { $jpg++ }
    if ($file.extension -eq '.ARW') { $arw++ }
    $i++

    $datetaken = ($file.fullname | GetDateTaken).Split(' ')[0]
    $datetaken_Day = $datetaken.Split('.')[0]
    $datetaken_Month = $datetaken.Split('.')[1]
    $datetaken_Year = $datetaken.Split('.')[2]

    $TargetPath = "$copy_to$datetaken_Year\$datetaken_Month\$datetaken_Day\"

    Write-Host ("$i. " + $file.Name + "   `tDate taken: " + $datetaken)
    
    robocopy $copy_from $TargetPath $file.Name /ts /fp /v /np /unilog+:$logifile | Out-Null

}

Write-Host ("`nTotal: " + $i + " files (" + $jpg + " JPG files, " + $arw + " ARW files)")
```

Not helps if write `$TargetPath = $copy_to + $datetaken_Year + "\" + $datetaken_Month + "\" + $datetaken_Day + "\"`.

Not helps if I set `/fat` option to robocopy.

But, for example, when I set a year manualy, everything is ok `$datetaken_Year = 2020`

What should be fixed to create correct folder names?

Comment: You do not show how `$copy_to` is populated.

Comment: Added a full script

Comment: this `foreach ($file in $file) {` is not the way it should be. [*grin*] the `$Collection` and the `$CurrentItem` otta have different names.

Comment: from reading your code, it seems likely the unwanted char is coming from the data source, not robocopy. have you tried sending that info thru `Format-Hex` to see what is really there?

Comment: foreach works, it is not a problem. In hex format output shows unwanted char C:\Photos\?2020\

I have no idea why or how to get rid of it. Tried to add .Trim(), not helps.

Comment: The problem is somewhere in GetDateTaken function. It returns ?13.?01.?2020 ??19:41

Comment: Possible solution is to clean $returnvalue.DateTaken from all chars except 0-9, dot and backslash. Actually, this is works, not sure why `$returnvalue.DateTaken -replace [char]8206 -replace [char]8207`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `GetDetailsOf()` method from the COM object returns localized results, which leads to your function on my Dutch machine returning the date in 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm' format (with invisible characters surrounding it).

A better approach IMO would be to get the date taken using `System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile` to read the exif data as null-terminated byte array and parse the date from that as DateTime object using below function:

```
function Get-ExifDate {
    # returns the 'DateTimeOriginal' property from the Exif metadata in an image file if possible
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByName')]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0, ParameterSetName = 'ByName')]
        [Alias('FullName', 'FileName')]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$Path,
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0, ParameterSetName = 'ByObject')]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$FileObject
    )

    Begin {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Drawing'
    }
    Process {
        # the function received a path, not a file object
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByName') {
            $FileObject = Get-Item -Path $Path -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
        # Parameters for FileStream: Open/Read/SequentialScan
        $streamArgs = @(
            $FileObject.FullName
            [System.IO.FileMode]::Open
            [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read
            [System.IO.FileShare]::Read
            1024,     # Buffer size
            [System.IO.FileOptions]::SequentialScan
        )
        try {
            $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $streamArgs
            $metaData = [System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile]::FromStream($stream)

            # get the 'DateTimeOriginal' property (ID = 36867) from the metadata
            # Tag Dec  TagId Hex  TagName           Writable  Group    Notes
            # -------  ---------  -------           --------  -----    -----
            # 36867    0x9003     DateTimeOriginal  string    ExifIFD  (date/time when original image was taken)

            # get the date taken as an array of bytes
            $exifDateBytes = $metaData.GetPropertyItem(36867).Value
            # transform to string, but beware that this string is Null terminated, so cut off the trailing 0 character
            $exifDateString = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($exifDateBytes).TrimEnd("`0")
            # return the parsed date
            return [datetime]::ParseExact($exifDateString, "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", $null) 
        }
        catch{
            Write-Warning -Message "Could not read Exif data from '$($FileObject.FullName)'"
        }
        finally {
            If ($metaData) {$metaData.Dispose()}
            If ($stream)   {$stream.Close()}
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another option would be to download and unzip [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/)
(you can download the zip files from [here](https://oliverbetz.de/pages/Artikel/ExifTool-for-Windows))

Then use it like:

```
$exifTool = 'Path\To\Unzipped\ExifTool.exe'  # don't forget to 'Unblock' after downloading
$file     = 'Path\To\The\ImageFile'          # fullname

# retrieve all date tags in the file
# -s2 (or -s -s) return short tag name add the colon directly after that
$allDates = & $exifTool -time:all -s2 $file  

# try to find a line with tag 'DateTimeOriginal', 'CreateDate' or 'ModifyDate'
# which will show a date format of 'yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss'
# and parse a DateTime object out of this string
$dateTaken = switch -Regex ($allDates) {
    '^(?:DateTimeOriginal|CreateDate|ModifyDate):\s(\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})' {
        [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss', $null)
        break
    }
}
```

---

**Short explanation of what the above returns**

Both methods return the date the image was taken as a [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) **object**, not a **string**.
This object has properties like `.Year`, `.Month`, `.Day` etc. It also has various methods like `.AddDays()`, `.ToShortDateString()`, `.ToString()` and a lot more.

If you do `$datetaken = ($datetaken -split ' ')[0]` as per your comment, you are asking PowerShell to *implicitely* convert it to a string using the **default** ToString() method.
You can use that ToString() method in your code if you give it the formatting string you need in between the brackets, anyway you like.

If you for instance do `$dateTaken.ToString('yyyy\\MM\\dd')`, you'll get a string `2020\10\08` if $dateTaken was today, which could serve as part of a file path.

In your code, you could do:

```
$TargetPath = Join-Path -Path $copy_to -ChildPath $dateTaken.ToString('yyyy\\MM\\dd')
# if that path does not exist yet, create it
if (!(Test-Path -Path $TargetPath -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $TargetPath -ItemType Directory
}
```

Then go ahead and copy the file to the now existing $TargetPath

Please have a look at all the [standard format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and [custom format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) you can use on a DateTime object.

Comment: @Sergei You may want to have a go with [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/). It's free software that by the look of it can handle many, many formats.

Comment: @Sergei I have added alternative code using ExifTool. I don't have any .ARW files myself, so please let us know if that works for those files too.

Comment: thank you.
The good news is that it works with ARW and JPG.

Unfortunately I cannot get how to split the returned date.
$datetaken returns a nice date in console "08.10.2020 2:08:51".
But if I do `$datetaken.Split(' ')[0]` I get an error "Method invocation failed because [System.DateTime] does not contain a method named 'Split'."

Comment: `write-host ($datetaken | Format-Hex)` - not works. Error: "Format-Hex : Cannot convert input of type System.DateTime to hexadecimal. To view the hexadecimal formatting of its string representation, pipe it to the Out-String cmdlet before piping it to Format-Hex."

`write-host ($datetaken | out-string | Format-Hex)` returns date in other format.

Comment: If I do `$datetaken = ($datetaken -split ' ')[0]` in works, but returns date in different format `01/13/2020`

Comment: @Sergei I have added extra explanation in my answer. Main thing is that the returned `$dateTaken` variable is not a **string**, but an **object** you can format in whatever way you need.